# How to store an array with two indices in the variable name?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array inside 2 for loops running over the indices i,j. I would like to store the array as a variable such that the variable carries an index [i,j]. How can I do this

```py
import numpy as np
n = 5
cond = [[[],[]] for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        H=np.array([[1,i],[3,j]])
        eig_values, eig_vectors = np.linalg.eig(H)
        eig_vectors[:,0][np.newaxis]
        cond[i,j] = eig_vectors[:,0][np.newaxis]
```

I get an error saying that 'list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple'

Comment: `cond` is undefined. What is its shape?

Comment: The error is clear you're trying to set one value, `cond[i,j]`, with a sequence. (`eig_vectors[:,0]` is a vector)

Comment: Do you need ``cond[i, j]`` or would ``cond[i][j]`` suffice?

Comment: Did you intend to initialize `cond` as a (n,n,2) array?

Comment: The index notation `[i, j]` only works for numpy arrays, for lists you access with `[i][j]`. Also, you cannot assign an `(i, j)` value to a list or array that is not previously defined as an `n x n` structure. For lists, you use `append`. For an array (better), create it first as indicated in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could declare `cond` as a `numpy` array, as an array of `zeros` for instance.
If I understood correctly, you want to store `eig_vectors[:,0]` for each `i, j`, which is what the code below does.

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
cond = np.zeros((n, n, 2)) # declare a numpy array of zeros of shape (n, n, 2)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        H=np.array([[1,i],[3,j]])
        eig_values, eig_vectors = np.linalg.eig(H)
        cond[i,j] = eig_vectors[:,0]
```